# Entity architecture in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, database-design, entity-relationship, model-associations

I want to implement a rating functionality within my site (mvc pattern).The entities are managed by an OR-Mapper (Doctrine).
A user should have the possibility to rate events, other users, posts etc.
This question is about how to build the correct entity architecture. My idea:

---

[1] Create one abstract Rating class to add fields that all ratings have (e.g. 'ratingAmount').Then, I would create a SubClass for EventRating, UserRating, PostRating etc. These subclasses get extra fields and the mapping field to the corresponding entity, e.g. the EventRating Class would be connected to the Event entity with a ManyToOne relation. For building that relation, I would add a $event field within the EventRating Class and in the Event entity a collection of ratings of type EventRating.

[2] Then I would create one RatingController to handle all ratings for all entities. I think creating also "SubControllers" wouldn't be right, e.g. EventRatingController would miss the mvc pattern.

---

Would this be a correct implementation or are there better ways to design that? I mean I could also create one big Rating class and add all "connection fields" to it, but I think that this wouldn't be the correct way to do it.

This question is more general, because you could also transfer the "Rating" functionality to a "Notification" functionality ,where Events can be connected to Notification, Post etc.

Regards.

Comment: I am using doctrine, my question was if my approach is ok or if there is any better regarding performance and Design. I think that sub rating classes sound logic but I m no pro in modelling :x

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers. Any more comments appreciated :) i also think there are always other ways you could Do this

Comment: Is my solution a good compromise? I mean you always need to refactor things, but for the beginning this should Do it